# Accessing public variables in the main class within other classes

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors

I am trying to port my game I made in Python to Java. In the Python version, I had all the methods and variables in one "class" and players were a dictionary like this:

game.py

```
...
new_player={"name":"","hp":0,...}
players=[]
//to add new player
players.append(new_player.copy())
```

Player's data values are then added separately:

```
...
players[0]["name"]="bob"
players[0]["hp"]=50
...
```

In the Java version, I have a separate class used to define a Player object, as well as a main method for the game.

For example (this is a small version):

game.java (returns omitted)

```
import java.utils.*;
public class game
{
    public static ArrayList<player> players = new ArrayList<player>();
    public static ArrayList<String> pdead = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int turn = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //do stuff
        players.add(new player(name));
        //do other stuff
    }
    public static void do_move(move)
    {
        //some move is selected
            players.get(turn).set_hp(10);
            //at this point compiler throws error: cannot find symbol
            //compiler does not recognize that a player should have
            //been added to the players variable
        //other stuff
    };
};
```

player.java (returns omitted)

```
public class player
{
    //arbitrary list of private variables like hp and name
    public player(new_name)
    {
        name = new_name;
        //other variables defined
    };
    public void set_hp(int amount) //Adding hp
    {
        hp += amount;
    };
    public void set_hp(int amount,String type) //taking damage
    {
        mana += amount;
        //go through types, armor, etc.
            hp -= amount;
    };
    public void display stats() //displays all player's stats before choosing move
    {
        //display stats until...
        //later in some for loop
            System.out.println(players.get(index).get_hp());
            //here compiler throws error again: cannot find symbol
            //players arraylist is in main class's public variables
        //other stuff
    };
    //other stuff
};
```

Supposedly, when the two classes-to-be are compiled together, the program will be able to run since the main variables are public and player variables are defined as the program goes on. However, the compiler does not recognize this and throws errors since the classes (in the same directory, by the way) do not read each other and objects are not "defined" in the array/arraylist while checking it.

How do you get the variables to be seen by the compiler as defined? I can upload the current working version of both classes and the final python version if need be, but I like to keep my games closed-source.

EDIT: fixed ArrayList initialization according to sjkm's reply

Comment: Java doesn't require that you close your `{}` brackets with `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the generic type of your lists:

change

```
public static ArrayList players = new ArrayList<player>();
public static ArrayList pdead = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to

```
public static ArrayList<player> players = new ArrayList<player>();
public static ArrayList<String> pdead = new ArrayList<String>();
```

otherwise you always have to cast the objects you get from the list...

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the errors in the main class, but how do I get player.java to see these variables? Also, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Which variables do you exactly want to access from inside the player class?

Comment: The players ArrayList is all I need to access for now in order to display statistics and to add hp based on a status effect based on players.size(). If I have others, I can use the same method. P.S. Why aren't we just chatting?

Comment: Access the player list like this: game.players | [Class].[Static_Public_Member]